# Impossible put at the top one image using a constraintlayout in android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-designer

I'm trying to put an image header at the top of the constraintlayout but when i run the app in a real device it is wrong and the header is not in the top:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="207dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_header" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

below we can see how looks it in a real device:

[image]

There is a space between the action bar and the header.
I tried to remove the action bar but also does not work.
Thanks in advance.

This is my content of ic_header:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="360dp"
    android:height="180dp"
    android:viewportWidth="360"
    android:viewportHeight="180">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0h360v180h-360z"
      android:fillColor="#fbc711"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: try to add `bottomToBottom=parent` and `vertical_bias=0.0`. Also run layout inspector tool to see if there's some padding or margin applied

Comment: Please share the contents of `drawable/ic_header`.

Comment: Hi @Pawel i added: app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" and there is not changes..-Chirag Kalra my "ic_header" is an xml file. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the src drawable and the `ImageView` both having a fixed height.

Try using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your `ImageView` xml, so that the source image expands to cover the empty area.

Comment: Hi Chirag I works being a xml file there is not problem but what happen if this is a png image i could loss information, anyways thanks I thinks that this fix by the moment the problem being a solid color, i can change his height without problems.

Comment: You could use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of a fixed height to avoid any cropping.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code and found out that given constraints are right but your SVG isn't scaling to the total length for your ImageView. You can see the view bounds below

[image]

**Solution:**
You can consider adding this line.

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

The result will be like the following image.

[image]

and the alternate solution is you can also use shape drawable if all you need is a solid layout.

And if you drawable isn't a solid color and some complex vector image. try not to resize your image view.
keep

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thanks this works using android:scaleType="fitXY" being a solid color there is not problem how it spands.

Comment: hey! You can try fixing your SVG though. you can try getting its size increased and give it a try.